# When I scale an element I want see the vertical overflow but set invisible the horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, z-index

I have several .cards inside my container. When I go with the mouse over a card I zoom in the card with the property `scale(1.5)`. But I want that the zoomed in card overflow the container instead the part in overflow isn't visible. To understand what is my goal it's enough remove the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties from the container. But in my case this isn't a solution beacause I don't want an horizontal scroll bar. Thus I thought to set: `overflow-x:hidden` and `overflow-y:visible` but doesn't work. Someone can detect the problem and point out me a solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    section {
      margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    
    section h2 {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #777777;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: visible;
      display: flex;
      z-index: -10;
      /* background-color: black; */
    }
    /* stile per i caroselli */
    /* stile generico per tutte la cards */
    
    .card {
      border-radius: 3px;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 1rem;
      box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -119px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
      width: 40%;
      margin-right: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.5s;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    /* .card:hover {
} */
    
    .second-section .card,
    .third-section .card,
    .fourth-section .card {
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    .card span {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    /* stili primo carosello */
    
    .card p {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      margin-top: 0.6rem;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .card:hover span {
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .card:hover p {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(2) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(3) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(4) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .card:hover {
      transform: scale(1.3);
      z-index: 2000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="second-section">
    <h2>Uscite indipendenti</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card"><span>Blues Brother</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>The Place</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>Jarhead</span></div>
      <div class="card">
        <span>E' stata la mano di Dio</span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis beatae explicabo, labore aut voluptatibus harum vero cum, soluta adipisci dolores repudiandae consequuntur exercitationem sint dolore quidem
        tempora nulla? Vitae, provident.
      </div>
      <div class="card"><span>E' stata la mano di Dio</span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

To clarify, this is the vertical expected result (open the full screen page).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    section {
      margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    
    section h2 {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #777777;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      display: flex;
      z-index: -10;
      /* background-color: black; */
    }
    /* stile per i caroselli */
    /* stile generico per tutte la cards */
    
    .card {
      border-radius: 3px;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 1rem;
      box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -119px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
      width: 40%;
      margin-right: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.5s;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    /* .card:hover {
    } */
    
    .second-section .card,
    .third-section .card,
    .fourth-section .card {
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    .card span {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    /* stili primo carosello */
    
    .card p {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      margin-top: 0.6rem;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .card:hover span {
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .card:hover p {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(2) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(3) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .container div:nth-child(4) {
      max-width: 30%;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .second-section .card:hover {
      transform: scale(1.3);
      z-index: 2000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="second-section">
    <h2>Uscite indipendenti</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card"><span>Blues Brother</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>The Place</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>Jarhead</span></div>
      <div class="card">
        <span>E' stata la mano di Dio</span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis beatae explicabo, labore aut voluptatibus harum vero cum, soluta adipisci dolores repudiandae consequuntur exercitationem sint dolore quidem
        tempora nulla? Vitae, provident.
      </div>
      <div class="card"><span>E' stata la mano di Dio</span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the desired result if you cannot see the cards due to overflow and not setting `overflow-x: scroll` in your section. Could you elaborate a bit more on what your desired result is?

Comment: @Kameron I modified my question to clarify the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the `overflow` style on `.container` and set the `overflow` on the `body`. Also, determined a height for `body` and `html` so the scrollbar shows at the bottom.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

section {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

section h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #777777;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-y: visible;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -10;
  /* background-color: black; */
}


/* stile per i caroselli */


/* stile generico per tutte la cards */

.card {
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -119px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* .card:hover {
} */

.second-section .card,
.third-section .card,
.fourth-section .card {
  width: 20%;
}

.card span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


/* stili primo carosello */

.card p {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.card:hover span {
  top: 0;
}

.card:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: -3px -153px 119px -70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
}

.second-section .container div {
  max-width: 30%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.second-section .container div:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 30%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
  background-size: cover;
}

.second-section .container div:nth-child(3) {
  max-width: 30%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
  background-size: cover;
}

.second-section .container div:nth-child(4) {
  max-width: 30%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1920/1040");
  background-size: cover;
}

.second-section .card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="second-section">
    <h2>Uscite indipendenti</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card"><span>Blues Brother</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>The Place</span></div>
      <div class="card"><span>Jarhead</span></div>
      <div class="card">
        <span>E' stata la mano di Dio Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis beatae explicabo, labore aut voluptatibus harum vero cum, soluta adipisci dolores repudiandae consequuntur exercitationem sint dolore quidem
        tempora nulla? Vitae, provident.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card"><span>E' stata la mano di Dio</span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that I upvoted. I changed overflow-x:hidden and it works.  I had tried a similar solution but in my solution there isn't height:100% in the body.  Why I need this property in this case?

Comment: @Umbert Because the `scrollbar` will show right under the `container` otherwise. With the `height` defined it will use all of the available window height. Therefore, showing it at the bottom of the window. I just made one more edit btw.

Comment: @Umbert Of course, I just added `flex-basis: 100%;` to the `card span` styles so that the `span`s with few words are now back aligned to the left and are using all the available flex space.